# column.OptionsFilter.ImmediateUpdateAutoFilter how to set it at run time

Tags: c#, filtering, devexpress, xtragrid

I need a mechanism that is not sending a filterquery for every keystroke the user types in the AutoFilterRow because this is to slow. can I catch some events after a user types a keystroke in a column of the AutoFilterRow ?

I mean, when user ends editing the filter value, and presses enter, that should be the time i want to handle the gridView_ColumnFilterChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

I could set column.OptionsFilter.ImmediateUpdateAutoFilter to true after binding the gridView ('cause i don't define any column before databinding.).
It does what i want, but i'm not sure if this is a good solution?